# How to concatenate the entity id with a string to generate a code user?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm developing an application using Symfony and Doctrine and I need to generate a code user, with a fixed prefix that contains always 5 numbers like (42153) to then append to the prefix the user id like (421530001), (421530002), (421530003).

I would like to do it in the class constructor, something like `$this->codeAd = ???`.

```
<?php

namespace Pharmagadir\AdhereBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Adhere
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="adhere")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pharmagadir\AdhereBundle\Repository\AdhereRepository")
 */
class Adhere
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->codeAd = ??? # <-- what to add here???
    }
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="codeAd", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $codeAd;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     *
     * @return Adhere
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Adhere
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }



    /**
     * Set codeAd
     *
     * @param string $codeAd
     *
     * @return Adhere
     */
    public function setCodeAd($codeAd)
    {
        $this->codeAd = $codeAd;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get codeAd
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCodeAd()
    {
        return $this->codeAd;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make it in the Entity constructor because the entity ID it's created only when you persist the object. So, **at the first look** the simplest solution to achieve this behavior (*there are other ways but it's an overkill for such a simple task*) is to use the `postPersist` [Doctrine event](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events):

> postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the
>   entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database
>   insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the
>   postPersist event.

Then you can implement it in your entity following [How to Work with Lifecycle Callbacks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/lifecycle_callbacks.html), and in your custom function:

```
/**
 * Adhere
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="adhere")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Pharmagadir\AdhereBundle\Repository\AdhereRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks() <--- add this line
 */
class Adhere
{
   #------------- other code

   /**
    * @ORM\PostPersist
    */
    public function setCodeAd()
    {
        // generate a random integer with 5 numbers like (42153)
        $randomCode = rand(10000, 99999);
        $this->codeAd = (string)$randomCode . $this->id;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**But why does the DB it's not updated with the value setted in the postPersist event???**

It's due to the explanation found on: [postupdate-postremove-postpersist events](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist), where is stated:

> The three post events are called inside EntityManager#flush(). Changes
>   in here are not relevant to the persistence in the database, but you
>   can use these events to alter non-persistable items, like non-mapped
>   fields, logging or even associated classes that are not directly
>   mapped by Doctrine.

So, to resolve this problem and apply the modification to the database, the simplest solution is to flush two time the same object like:

```
$ad = new AdHere();
$this->em->persist($ad);
$this->em->flush();
$this->em->persist($ad);
$this->em->flush();
```

Comment: Thanks, i try it now but i get in the database after persist just the randomcode without the id in the right. and i need to generate the id in the right with 4 numbers like that (0001)

Comment: I've edited the answer using the `postPersist` event instead of the initially `prePersist`. What have you tried? Maybe you don't see that change, you have to use the `postPersist` event.

Comment: I use it with the PrePersist the codeAd is generated in the database but it contain juste the randomcode without the id. i use it with your new answer with the PostPersist but i get an error the codeAd cannot be null

Comment: this is because of this line `@ORM\Column(name="codeAd", type="string", length=255)`, you have to add `nullable=true` to that line like `@ORM\Column(name="codeAd", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)` and remember to execute `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` to apply the change on DB.

Comment: When i use nullable=true, after persist with (PostPersist) i get Null in the database

Comment: have you added the annotation `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()` on your entity class as described by the docs?

Comment: Yes i added it, thats why i get a randomcode in the database with the PrePersist. the problem now with the id, in the database i get juste codeAd = $randomcode witout the $this->id like that (42784)

Comment: so strange... as you can read in my answer (from the docs) "_Generated primary key values are available in the postPersist event_". I cannot check in this moment, I need 1 hour to make some checks :-)

Comment: I fix the randomCode with 12345, in the database i get Null with the PostPersist, and with the PrePersist i get 12345

Comment: As already said entity ID cannot be `null` in the `postPersist` event. There must be something more but now I cannot check it (I'm not at home, I will be in 1 hour). Try adding `return $this;` in the function but I don't think it will be useful.

Comment: Ok no problem thanks, i use it with the return but same problem

Comment: I've updated the answer with the simplest fix to achieve your needs. PS: My answer does not include the solution to format the Id because I've noticed that you already have found the solution! :-)

Comment: Its okey man thanks i already did this solution and it work :D two flush in the controller